# How do I get an image to show up when I paste a URL from a website into facebook or slack, etc

Tags: image, url, hyperlink

I'm creating a website that I want people to share and when they share a link I want them to see an image that I curate. How can I set that up?

The site relies heavily on javascript and background images... is that maybe why nothing is turning up automatically?

The main places this would be nice are: Facebook, Slack, Pinterest, ... places like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to generate nice preview links you need to do some additional work.
To control how your link would be viewed you would need to set up special meta tags. For example,Facebook uses **Open Graph** tags:

```
<meta property="og:image"
content="http://graphics.myfavnews.com/images/logo-100x100.jpg" />
```

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

Comment: Thanks! I will try this.